# PHP code unable to differentiate between Chrome and Safari

Tags: php

I'm trying to show the browser that I used to open my site using Codeigniter User Agent Libraries. When I open with Safari, User agent return the right value. But when I open with Chrome, it return "Safari" value.

here is part of my code:

```
var broswer  = '<?php echo $agent = $this->agent->browser(); ?>';
   alert(broswer);
  if(broswer != 'Chrome')
  {
    alert('Please use Google Chrome only.');
    return false;
  }
```

The alert says 'Safari' even when the browser is Chrome.The issue happens only in IOS,works perfectly for Chrome and Firefox on Android.
Please help me out..

Comment: `$this->agent` is [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/user_agent.html) right? You might want to add that as a tag (I'd do it, but I'd like you to confirm that first).

Comment: Yes..its CodeIgniter.I'm a bit new to PHP can you suggest how to add the tag.I just checked I'm getting the same issue with Firefox in Ios